# Codeigniter login to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey! I'm very new to Codeigniter, I'm trying to protect the entire admin controller. I figured I'd start here:

```
function Admin()
{
    parent::Controller();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])){
        $this->login();
    }
}
```

but this is obviously incomplete. How do I also stop the method that is trying to run ( ie index() ), and am I on the right track here??

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is

Extend the base controllers:
**MY_Controller.php**

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
      parent::Controller();
      $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
      $this->data['user'] = $this->user_lib->get($user_id);
    }
}
?>
```

you can store all kinds of info in this construct. This just gets the currently logged in users ID and assigns it the `$data['user']` . This will be adjusted depending on which sort of auth library you use but you get the gist. You now have access to the current users ID, and all their details, from within any controller that extends "MY_Controller"

now you can create an "admin" controller, or any number of other ones to restrict access. like so:
**Admin_Controller.php**

```
<?php
class Admin_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        if($this->data['user']['group'] !== 'admin')
        {
            show_error('Error - you need to be an admin.');
        }
    }

}
?>
```

**Public_controller.php**

```
<?php
class Public_Controller extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        if($this->data['user']['group'] !== 'member')
        {
            show_error('You need to login to see this page...');
        }
    }

}
?>
```

as you can see..possibilities are endless

So, for admin only pages - use the admin controller
for member only pages - public
for "normal" pages - use the default controller.

I'll link to [Phil Sturgeon's](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY) article as it's where I read about it first

Answer (score 0):

put the checking session code in every function in Admin Controller that you want to protect.
that is the easiest way to do it..

Comment: Thanks....that's what I was afraid of. Seems like there would be a 'DRYer' way though.